# Lowering the prime symbol

Tags: math-mode, superscripts

I want to use a prime along a math symbol, but now it looks a little odd, e.g. like this:
[image: prime]

I would like to lower the prime, if possible. Is there a nice way to do this?

Comment: stripping off all really irrelevant stuff, the code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 10pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
%stuff
\begin{equation}
\Phi(p\triangleleft g)=\Phi(p_2)\triangleleft'g
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

and so on. I would like to prime to be such that the upper edge of the triangle is sort of on level with the middle of the prime.

Comment: "I would like to lower the prime" -- by how much? E.g,, would you like the symbol to be centered on the math centerline? Please be specific.

Comment: What a big prime have you got: could you show the code that produces the picture you posted?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Is it that big?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following implementation of `\myprime` may be what you're looking for.

```
\newcommand\myprime{\mkern-3.5mu\raise0.6ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\prime$}}
```

The `\mkern-3.5mu` instruction shifts the material to the left, while `\raise0.6ex` raises it a bit.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} % Palatino clone text and math font
\newcommand\myprime{\mkern-3.5mu\raise0.6ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\prime$}}

\begin{document}
$\Phi(p_2)\triangleleft\myprime g$ vs.\ $\Phi(p_2)\triangleleft' g$
\end{document}
```

Here's the same screenshot, but with `mathpazo` loaded instead of `newpxtext` and `newpxmath`:

[image]

---

*Addendum*: To create more space *after* the lowered prime symbol, one could insert an instruction such as `\mkern5mu`. In case you're wondering how wide a "mu" is: There are 18 `mu` in 1 `em`. :-) Thus, the following definition may work for you:

```
\newcommand\lowprime{\mkern-3.5mu%
                     \raise0.6ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\prime$}
                     \mkern5mu}
```

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\newcommand\myprime{\mkern-3.5mu%
                    \raise0.6ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\prime$}}
\newcommand\lowprime{\mkern-3.5mu%
                     \raise0.55ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\prime$}
                     \mkern5mu}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
$\Phi(p_2)\triangleleft\myprime g$  & \verb+\myprime+\\
$\Phi(p_2)\triangleleft\lowprime g$ & \verb+\lowprime+\\
$\Phi(p_2)\triangleleft^{\prime}g$  & \verb+^{\prime}+ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That did it! Did you add the newpxtext and newpxmath (which made the triangle smaller) just for giggles or?

Comment: Also: Jabba, you're a wonderful human being.

Comment: @B.Pasternak - Actually, I started writing my answer before you posted a fully compilable example, and I thus had to guess which font you were using. I could tell it was some type of Palatino clone, and I simply worked with the first guess (`newpxtext` and `newpxmath`) that seemed about right. The output that's produced by loading `mathpazo` instead of `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` is quite similar, really. I've just posted a second screenshot, showing what's produced with `mathpazo`. The main difference indeed occurs with `\triangleleft`.

Comment: @B.Pasternak - A little-known fact: My illustrious ancestor of Tatooine, to whom I bear more than just a passing resemblance, was an early adopter of the TeX typesetting system! :-)

Comment: Thanks very much, that is clear. One more thing: you say that the mkern part shifts "the material" to the let, which it does, but it takes the symbols after the prime with it, and I would rather not have that. However, deleting it in the definition didn't help. So basically the lowering is perfect (and I can see how to adjust it as well), but I would just like to having the space with the symbols following the new prime to be as before. Is that possible?